# What are the downsides to putting my entire Redux state in one slice?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I started creating multiple slices in redux-toolkit, but didn't know what the benefit was for creating multiple slices and multiple reducers in those slices. I came up with an idea to put much less work into creating reducers and slices, while still being able to access any part of the state using a "setter" like [lodash _.set()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-set-method/#)

#### Example General Reducer

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import generalReducer from '../slices/general'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    general: generalReducer,
  },
})
```

In that general slice, I would have a reducer  `updateValue` that would take a value and path, and I could set the value of any object using the object path. Then I wouldn't need to keep creating one-off reducers for each part of the state, or multiple reducers.

```
import _set from "@/assets/helpers/objects/_set";
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const generalSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logout: () => initialState,
    updateValue: (state, action) => {
      const { path, value } = action.payload;
      _set(state, path, value);
    },
  },
});
```

What would be the downsides to doing this?

Comment: See the Redux style guide, especially [Model Actions as Events, Not Setters](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#model-actions-as-events-not-setters). If you use it like you do, you gain nothing from using Redux, as you are skipping all Redux-like patterns. Another library would probably a better fit if you really want to keep using global state like that.

Comment: I just restructured the whole app using multiple slices and combining those slices into one reducer. Turnes out that when you combine the reducer, changing one slice doesn't hydrate the other slices. If everything was under general, the whole app would refresh.

Note: I still use the _set functionality to access properties within each slice.

Comment: Again: if you want to do this, please use another state management library. You are not using patterns Redux is built for anyways, and there are state mgmt libraries made to actually work that way. I am telling you this from the position of being a Redux maintainer. If you want an event-sourcing-based approach, Redux is great. If you only want setters, probably look at MobX or Valtio. You are not using any benefits of Redux right now.